# An odd combo-puzzle! (Franken-puzzle?)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Here's what you get:

[image: puzzle image]

<sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup>Body needs to be 30 characters! :):)</sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub>

Comment: You can edit out the quality-bot-enforced useless parts after you've managed to post the question.

Comment: @Bass -- Oh, really? Thanks! I'll try that!

Comment: @Bass -- Unfortunately, it turns out I can't...

Comment: Ah, apparently there's a hard limit of 30 characters in addition to the softer limit of "this looks like a low quality post to my senseless AI brain" the bot enforces. Sorry for getting your hopes up :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start with interpreting the elements within the picture:

> - We have a ciphertext. Pretty obvious
>  - We have a red cardigan. The "-ig" suggests we should remove the substring "ig" from the word, leaving "cardan"
>  - We have a face mask. This strongly suggest we need to mask the ciphertext somehow, and having the word "cardan", this hints towards a [cardan grille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardan_grille)
>  - We have a recycle bin with the numbers 714. And since we still need a mask for the cipher, 714 is probably that in some way, shape, or form.
>  - And the arrows also match up with this interpretation nicely, the cardan being the center of action.

Diving deeper into the trash bin:

> Putting the number 714 into a bin suggests we should convert that number to binary, which would also serve as a nice mask, since each bit only has two states. Without padding, 714 has 10 bits in binary. Now lets take that as our mask and repeat the binary representation once we hit the 11th letter. Interpret '1' as "included letter" and '0' as not included letter
>
> ```
> LWETHZSCGXEWTCAROVOIKAIN
> 101100101010110010101011
> ```

This yields the answer

> LETS GET COOKIN

Comment: Wow! Another great answer from you, Lukas! Green check coming your way soon!